# Using React, how can I maintain state while playing and pausing a video?

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video, state

I'm building a video player in React and I'm trying to keep track of whether or not the video is playing. Naturally, I'm thinking of using React state to set a boolean to true or false.

The problem is that whenever I play the video and try to update the state, my video seems to be reloaded to the DOM and the play / pause state is lost.

```
const refVideo = useRef();
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

function playVideo() {
  if(refVideo && refVideo.current) {
    if(refVideo.current.paused) {
      setIsPlaying(true);
      refVideo.current.requestFullscreen();
      refVideo.current.play();
    } else {
      setIsPlaying(false);
      refVideo.current.pause();
    }
  }
  return false;
}

return (
  <section>
    <video src="video.mp4" ref={refVideo}></video>
    <Button onClick={(e) => playVideo(e)} text="Play / Pause />
  </section>
);
```

My `Button` component handles the `playVideo()` function but `setIsPlaying(true)` seems to re-render the video, preventing it from playing. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

One recommendation for maintaining state on re-render would be using a state manager such as Redux. Creating a pause or play alongside a player timestamp can ensure that the player maintains both status and position on any React render changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using that boolean in a cookie? In that way you dont have to change the state and re render. You look at the cookie on the onClick event and then change the boolean and play or stop the video. Just an idea

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the default html5 player in my react app but I need the UI to depend on whether the video is playing or not. Setting up a simple event listener in my useEffect function worked for me:

```html
videoRef.current.addEventListener('play', () => {
 setVideoPlaying(true)
})
videoRef.current.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  setVideoPlaying(false)
})
```